# Disable click on this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable click event only on current item with class

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item', function() {
  $(".item").removeClass('is-expanded');
  $(this).addClass('is-expanded');
  $(".item").each(function(){   
    $(".item").click(true).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(".is-expanded").click(false).css("cursor", "default");
  });
```

however, I can still click on item with class `.is-expanded` while it shouldn't as we only click on all other items without that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your logic, you want:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {
    $(".item").removeClass('is-expanded');
    $(this).addClass('is-expanded');
});
```

And set cursor in CSS, as you should:

```
.item {
   cursor: pointer;
}

.item.is-expanded {
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: yes ok, that's for the simple css bit. WHich is ok. I am more talking about the click event

Comment: @rob.m Ya, check the selector param: `'.item:not(.is-expanded)'` in this answer. Because basically, still if i get your logic, you don't want `.is-expanded` elements to be clickable

Comment: bingo! I was actually using 'not' but wrongly somewhere else. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

When using the `on()` method you're detecting the click, or other named event, on the element(s) to which the method is chained, and look to see where it originated. Once the even has already bubbled up it can't be prevented (because it's already happened).

You could, however, attach the event-listener to the elements themselves, and assess the current class:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-expanded')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // do whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, u need unbind

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
$('.item').click(function() {
  $(".item").removeClass('is-expanded');
  $(this).addClass('is-expanded').unbind('click');
});
```

If u need ricovery the click, instead:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.item').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-expanded')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $(".item").removeClass('is-expanded');
      $(this).addClass('is-expanded');
    }
  });
});
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/c8WUE2iH1iKuJBvW8OG6/preview